# "What is そいつら and what kind of conjugation is 知らんからな?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, conjugations, slang

I was wondering what そいつら means, and is 知らんからな slang? Here is the sentence:

> 俺はそいつらのことよく知らんからな。

I know they slur their vowels to make things easier to say.  Or maybe this is a new word that I can't find in the dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

そいつら means "they"(or more precisely "the fellows"). When "ら" is added to a pronoun, it becomes a plural one. For example, 彼 means he, and 彼ら means they.

知らん means 知らない, which is kinda oral expression.
The whole sentence means "because I don't know much about them".